# How to get my website to use the same version of php as Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, redhat

I'm on a Linux Redhat server, and when I run `php -v` I get PHP 8.2.15

However, on my wordpress, website when I run `phpinfo();` I get 7.3.33.

[image]

How do I update my server settings to use php 8.2 everywhere, or just specifically in my site root?
I already tried an `AddHandler` to configure php 8.2 in my .htaccess file; that does nothing.

I've found some similar questions online, but most of them are the reverse--the correct version of php is used on the site, but the incorrect version in the cli.

Comment: If you have a WordPress installation that uses PHP 7.3, you can't just tell it to start using PHP 8.3 and expect everything to still work fine. You'll need to make sure that your current version of WordPress actually works with PHP 8.3, else you'll need to [update WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/) as well.

Comment: Also note, there is no 8.3.15. You might mean 8.2.15, which is the latest patch version of the 8.2 branch.

Comment: `most of them are the reverse--the correct version of php is used on the site, but the incorrect version in the cli` ...define "correct". They are simply "different" versions. The web instance and the CLI instance have different configurations. So the solution ought to be similar, whichever one you want to update. This is old but might still be relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses . You can google more for similar suggestions.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Typo on my part--updated the question to say 8.2.15. The latest version of WP (6.4) is compatible with PHP 8.2 and I want to upgrade both

Comment: @ADyson "correct" meaning the version of PHP that I want my site to use, that is, 8.2 :) whereas php 7.3 is no longer receiving security updates

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what I mean is from the point of view of your example about CLI vs web being wrong, your situation is just vice versa so it doesn't really matter which one is "wrong"

Comment: @ADyson the answers to the question about the "CLI" being wrong are "It doesn't matter if the CLI version is wrong, as long as your phpinfo() version is correct, it doesn't affect your website." they do not provide answers on how to actually update the php version that is used in phpinfo(), which is what I'm looking for

Comment: Did https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses not help you?

Comment: I tried some of the suggestions there but ultimately I'm running into an error when restarting apache so I cannot test if they worked or not... once I figure that out maybe this will help!